# R subsetting if both conditions are met

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame `df.1` based on two conditions:

1. observations in `Accession` variable should contain `；`
2. observations in `kinase.or.not` should be `kinase`

Below is the code I used. But it seems that the first condition `grep(";", df.1$Accession)` is ignored. Why is that? Thanks!

```
df.2 <- df.1[grep(";", df.1$Accession) & df.1$kinase.or.not == "Kinase",]
```

Answer (score 2):

We need `grepl` instead of `grep` - the difference is `grep` returns the numeric position index whereas `grepl` returns a logical vector which can be used along with `&` to join the compound expression

```
df.1[grepl(";", df.1$Accession) & df.1$kinase.or.not == "Kinase",]
```

Comment: You are right! It works when I use `grepl`. But why `grep` cannot do its job in the same way?

Comment: @Dr.ChemBio As I mentioned, you are using a logical expression with one that is returning numeric index and the number of elements of grep will be equal to the number of TRUE values creating all sorts of problems you can imageine